# Spring Boot Jpa Batch - CannotCreateTransactionException

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-batch, datasource

I have a Spring Boot + JPA + Spring batch (+Spring Integration) project. Also there's Flyway, configured apart.
I have configured spring batch to use a different datasource than default "spring.jpa.datasource". This is fine.
Inside my tasklet I query on two datasources, first query on ds1 goes right, second query on ds2 goes wrong:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@2fb082ff] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [main]
```

More details:
I have a configuration class for each datasource, annotated with

```
@Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
```

In each configuration a bean for DataSource, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and JpaTransactionManager is defined, with custom name.

A service is defined for each datasource as:

```
 @Service @Transactional(transactionManager=JpaApsConfiguration.APS_TRANSACTION_MANAGER, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

and a entitymanager is autowired using the right qualifier
(note: query made through JpaRepository classes)

Any suggestion on what could cause this behaviour? Thanks

Note:

- Database connects successfully
- I had a different error before
  (already fixed, but maybe could be helpful):
  'NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException' as  Spring couldn't    identify the
  correct 'PlatformTransactionManager' between my two    transaction
  manager beans and the default transactionManager.

EDIT:

Here the complete stacktrace for the error:

2018-05-08 12:12:24 INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [STEP#PROCESS_SHIPMENTS]
2018-05-08 12:12:24 ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step STEP#PROCESS_SHIPMENTS in job PROCESS_APS
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@351e89fc] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [main]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at dkr.astreconnector.service.GespeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$73dbb368.getValueDetailByUniq()
    at dkr.astreconnector.batch.worker.ShipmentProcessor.process(ShipmentProcessor.java:63)
    at dkr.astreconnector.batch.worker.ShipmentProcessor.process(ShipmentProcessor.java:30)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:303)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:202)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:790)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at dkr.astreconnector.AstreConnectorBatchApplication.main(AstreConnectorBatchApplication.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@351e89fc] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [main]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:193)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:425)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
2018-05-08 12:12:24 INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=PROCESS_APS]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=128}] and the following status: [FAILED]

Comment: Can you add complete stack trace of error you are getting?

Comment: Added stack trace as requested. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907206/could-not-open-jpa-entitymanager-for-transaction-nested-exception-is-java-lang

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: by the way I've already used those hints to debug my code but sadly without results

Comment: Finally I've _SOLVED_ the issue: simply in my batch configuration I have explicitly declared the qualifier for transaction manager, which then is passed to my job creation factory. @Autowired
 @Qualifier("transactionManager")
 private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

Comment: Can you add your solution to the question?

Comment: we are also facing same kind of issue, how did you resolve it, kindly explain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit late, but I'd like to reply to @mad_fox

Primary db:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = JpaAppsConfiguration.APPS_ENTITY_MANAGER,
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
    basePackages = { JpaAppsConfiguration.APPS_REPOSITORIES })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JpaAppsConfiguration {

public final static String APPS_PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "apps";
public final static String APPS_DATA_SOURCE = "appDs";
public final static String APPS_ENTITY_MANAGER = "appsEmf";
public final static String APPS_TRANSACTION_MANAGER = "appsTm";
protected final static String APPS_PACKAGES = ""; //my models package
protected final static String APPS_REPOSITORIES = ""; //my repos package

@Primary
@Bean(name = APPS_DATA_SOURCE)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource appsDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = APPS_ENTITY_MANAGER)
@PersistenceContext(unitName = APPS_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean appsEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier(APPS_DATA_SOURCE) DataSource appsDataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = builder
            .dataSource(appsDataSource)
            .persistenceUnit(APPS_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
            .packages(APPS_PACKAGES)
            .build();

    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return emf;
}
}
```

Secondary db:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = JpaGepeConfiguration.GEPE_ENTITY_MANAGER, 
    basePackages = { JpaGepeConfiguration.GEPE_REPOSITORIES })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JpaGepeConfiguration {

public static final String GEPE_PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "gn1";
public static final String GEPE_DATA_SOURCE = "gn1ds";
public static final String GEPE_ENTITY_MANAGER = "gn1emf";
public static final String GEPE_TRANSACTION_MANAGER = "gn1tm";
public static final String GEPE_PACKAGES = ""; //my models package
public static final String GEPE_REPOSITORIES = ""; //my repos package

@Bean(name = GEPE_DATA_SOURCE)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "gn1.datasource")
public DataSource gepeDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = GEPE_ENTITY_MANAGER)
@PersistenceContext(unitName = GEPE_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean gepeEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier(GEPE_DATA_SOURCE) DataSource gepeDataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = builder
            .dataSource(gepeDataSource)
            .persistenceUnit(GEPE_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
            .packages(GEPE_PACKAGES)
            .build();

    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return emf;
}
}
```

Methods in @Service classes for primary db are annotated as:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = JpaAppsConfiguration.APPS_TRANSACTION_MANAGER, readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Parameters in properties file are as follows:

```
#DATABASE CONNECTION
#Primary
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=
spring.datasource.url=j
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=
spring.datasource.name=
#Secondary
gepe.datasource.username=
gepe.datasource.password=
gepe.datasource.driverClassName=
gepe.datasource.url=
gepe.datasource.jdbcUrl=
gepe.datasource.name=
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: APPS_TRANSACTION_MANAGER is not configured anywhere. it just defined as a final string.
how does @TRansactional annotation will make use of this ? 
isn't it should be "transactionManager" instead of APPS_TRANSACTION_MANAGER?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet for batch configuration. Make sure that you also override *getTransactionManager* method. (replace the value of qualifires with yours)

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("primaryTransactionManager")
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);

        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find a minimalistic working example of DefaultBatchConfigurer implementation to just specify DataSource and TransactionManager anywhere so: thank you for that, works like a charm!